# Can not convert HTML file to PDF on server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, wkhtmltopdf, pechkin

I try to use pechkin.dll to convert HTML file to PDF. At localhost it works. But when I upload project to server, I can't convert the file. I get an error: "internal server error 500". Can you tell how to solve this problem ? Please help.

This is ajax script (it works fine)

```
var HTML = document.documentElement.outerHTML.toString();
            console.log(HTML.toString());
            var dataToSend = JSON.stringify({'test': HTML});
            console.log(dataToSend);
$.ajax({
    url: "medicalPrintForm.aspx/test",
    data: dataToSend,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
    success: OnSuccess,
    error: OnError
});
```

This is my code to convert file in code behind

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
public static string test(string test)
{
    convertFunction(test);
    return test;      
}

private static void convertFunction(string test)
{
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["insertID"].ToString());

    string fileName1 = @"D:\web\Mcer\HtmlPage1.html";

    if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName1)))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName1));
        FileStream file = File.Create(fileName1);
        StreamWriter wt = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8);
        wt.WriteLine(test);
        file.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        File.Delete(fileName1);
        FileStream file = File.Create(fileName1);
        StreamWriter wt = new StreamWriter(file, Encoding.UTF8);
        wt.WriteLine(test);
        file.Close();
    }


    //convert html to pdf
    var pechkin = Factory.Create(new GlobalConfig());
    var pdf = pechkin.Convert(new ObjectConfig()
                                .SetLoadImages(true).SetZoomFactor(1.5)
                                .SetPrintBackground(true)
                                .SetScreenMediaType(true)
                                .SetCreateExternalLinks(true)
                                .SetPageUri("http://192.168.24.36/medcer/HtmlPage1.html"));

    //return pdf file
    SqlConnection EMR_Conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.24.36;Initial Catalog=EMR;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=bpk$1234");
    EMR_Conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select hncode from MED_main where rowID = '" + id + "'", EMR_Conn);
    SqlDataReader dr;
    DataTable dt;
    String hn = "";
    string printerName = HttpContext.Current.Session["pathPrint"].ToString();

    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(dr);
    if (dt.Rows.Count != 0)
    {
        hn = dt.Rows[0]["hncode"].ToString().Trim();
    }
    dr.Close();
    EMR_Conn.Close();
    if (hn != "")
    {
        string fileName = @"D:\web\Mcer\PDFs\" + id + ")" + hn + ".pdf";
        if (!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName));
            FileStream file = File.Create(fileName);
            file.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
            file.Close();
            //print function
            Process printJob = new Process();
            printJob.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
            printJob.StartInfo.Arguments = printerName;
            printJob.StartInfo.Verb = "printto";
            printJob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            printJob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            PrinterSettings setting = new PrinterSettings();
            setting.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            printJob.Start();
            printJob.Close();
        }
        else
        {
            File.Delete(fileName);
            FileStream file = File.Create(fileName);
            file.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
            file.Close();
            //print function

            Process printJob = new Process();
            printJob.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
            printJob.StartInfo.Arguments = printerName;
            printJob.StartInfo.Verb = "printto";
            printJob.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            printJob.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            PrinterSettings setting = new PrinterSettings();
            setting.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;
            printJob.Start();
            printJob.Close();

        }
    }
}
```

Help me please. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think your hardcoded filename1 value might be the problem, are you sure "D:\web\Mcer\HtmlPage1.html" exists on your server

Comment: i solve this already becuase of in the server side not have adobe reader. Thank you for reply

Comment: Please add that as an accepted answer, so this question is marked as answered.